# File is getting locked after renameTo method (JAVA, Windows, JDK6)

Tags: java, file, file-rename, jdk6

I am renaming the extension of the file from .tmp to .xml, but when I try to access the same file from other path, it gives me an exception that file is locked.

```
String filename= "TemporaryFile.tmp";
File file = new File(filename);
String filename1 = file.getPath().replace(".tmp",".xml");
File file1 = new File(filename1);
if(file.renameTo(file1)){
System.out.println("File is successfully renamed");
}
```

Here, the file gets successfully renamed but is locked by some process and couldn't be accessed for further processing.
I have tried using `file.canWrite();` which returns false, and even tried modifying its state with `setReadable()` and `setExecutable()` methods, but nothing works. Any help on this would be appreciated. 
Please note I can't use any other JDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String filename= "TemporaryFile.tmp";
    File file = new File(filename);
    String filename1 = file.getPath().replace(".tmp",".xml");
    File file1 = new File(filename1);
    if(file.renameTo(file1)){
        System.out.println("File is successfully renamed");
        System.out.println("Can write file: " + file.canWrite());
        System.out.println("Can write file1: " + file1.canWrite());

    }
```

the output:
**File is successfully renamed**

**Can write file: false**

**Can write file1: true**

Java Doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)
Postback if that worked.